# Cocos2d draw method

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I make app with cocos2d. In init method I load some sprites. I override draw method and don't call it. But when I start my app don't see my sprites only black screen and draw method is called automatically. Why draw method hide my sprites and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've subclassed CCSprite, are you calling `[super draw]`?

```
- (void) draw
{
   [super draw];
   // your stuff
}
```